# Next JS code inside getInitialProps not executes after page reload

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm integrating NextJS into my React app. I face a problem, on page reload or opening direct link(ex. somehostname.com/clients) my `getInitialProps` not executes, but if I open this page using `<Link>` from `next/link` it works well. I don't really understand why it happens and how to fix it. I have already came throught similar questions, but didn't find any solution which could be suitable for me.

Clients page code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { ClientsTable } from '../../src/components/ui/tables/client-table';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import { AddClientModal } from '../../src/components/ui/modals/add-client-modal';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import { Alert } from '../../src/components/ui/alert';
import { Color } from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';
import { AppState } from '../../src/store/types';
import { thunkAddClient, thunkGetClients } from '../../src/store/thunks/clients';
import { SnackbarOrigin } from '@material-ui/core';
import { IClientsState } from '../../src/store/reducers/clients';
import { NextPage } from 'next';
import { ReduxNextPageContext } from '../index';
import { PageLayout } from '../../src/components/ui/page-layout';

const Clients: NextPage = () => {
  const [addClientModalOpened, setAddClientModalOpened] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [alertType, setAlertType] = useState<Color>('error');
  const [showAlert, setAlertShow] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const alertOrigin: SnackbarOrigin = { vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center' };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { clients, isLoading, hasError, message, success } = useSelector<AppState, IClientsState>(state => state.clients);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      handleAddModalClose();
    }
  }, [success]);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAlert();
  }, [hasError, success, isLoading]);

  function handleAddModalClose(): void {
    setAddClientModalOpened(false);
  }

  function handleAddClient(newClientName: string): void {
    dispatch(thunkAddClient(newClientName));
  }

  function checkAlert() {
    if (!isLoading && hasError) {
      setAlertType('error');
      setAlertShow(true);
    } else if (!isLoading && success) {
      setAlertType('success');
      setAlertShow(true);
    } else {
      setAlertShow(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <PageLayout>
      <div className='clients'>
        <h1>Clients</h1>

        <div className='clients__add'>
          <div className='clients__add-text'>
            Add client
          </div>
          <Fab color='primary' aria-label='add' size='medium' onClick={() => setAddClientModalOpened(true)}>
            <AddIcon/>
          </Fab>

          <AddClientModal
            opened={addClientModalOpened}
            handleClose={handleAddModalClose}
            handleAddClient={handleAddClient}
            error={message}
          />
        </div>

        <Alert
          open={showAlert}
          message={message}
          type={alertType}
          origin={alertOrigin}
          autoHideDuration={success ? 2500 : null}
        />

        {isLoading && <CircularProgress/>}

        {!isLoading && <ClientsTable clients={clients}/>}

      </div>
    </PageLayout>
  );
};

Clients.getInitialProps = async ({ store }: ReduxNextPageContext) => {
  await store.dispatch(thunkGetClients());
  return {};
};

export default Clients;
```

thunkGetClients()

```
export function thunkGetClients(): AppThunk {
  return async function(dispatch) {
    const reqPayload: IFetchParams = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/clients'
    };

    try {
      dispatch(requestAction());

      const { clients } = await fetchData(reqPayload);

      console.log(clients);

      dispatch(getClientsSuccessAction(clients));

    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(requestFailedAction(error.message));
    }
  };
}
```

_app.tsx code

```
import React from 'react';
import App, { AppContext, AppInitialProps } from 'next/app';

import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { makeStore } from '../../src/store';
import { Store } from 'redux';

import '../../src/sass/app.scss';
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';

export interface AppStore extends Store {
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, any>;
}

export interface MyAppProps extends AppInitialProps {
  store: AppStore;
}

export default withRedux(makeStore)(
  class MyApp extends App<MyAppProps> {
    static async getInitialProps({
                                   Component,
                                   ctx
                                 }: AppContext): Promise<AppInitialProps> {
      const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps
        ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
        : {};

      return { pageProps };
    }

    render() {
      const { Component, pageProps, store } = this.props;

      return (
        <>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Provider>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

Looking for your advices and help. Unfortunately, I couldn't find solution by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way Next.js works, it runs `getInitialProps` on first page load (reload or external link) in the **server**, and rest of pages that where navigated to with `Link` it will run this method on **client**.

The reason for this is to allow Next.js sites to have "native" SEO version.

Comment: What is the right way to load data after page reload? I have tried to load it by the same way as without next, but it didn't work. (Dispatched action inside useEffect on component load)

Comment: useEffect hook will run only in the browser, do u see the request in the network tab?

Comment: well, I see request for the page by the route, but returned page have no any daat from API. (I don't see that data call gave been triggered after page relaod)

Comment: You won't see your api call on the browser when it runs on the server, put console.log after your api call, check that you see your data in the terminal

Comment: hmm,  I have rebuilded project some time and it started work again. seems like `next run dev script` not working properly sometimes. But thank you .